# Magento 2 rest api throws 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: api, rest, magento2

I have create a user role in Magento 2 and a new user 
[image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPb2u.png)

I used in Chrome the application Postman:

In the GET box: http://example.com/php.index/rest/V1/products/
In Type use Basic Auth with Username and Password

But I get this status '401 Unauthorized' and this requests:

```
    {
  "message": "Consumer is not authorized to access %resources",
  "parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Catalog::products"
  }
}
```

I can login in Magento backend with the user and password

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass basic Authorization with access key in header:

## Step 1:

Call API: **/V1/integration/admin/token** with parameters:

```
username=your_admin_username
password=your_admin_password
```

This will give you an access key like **at0o6w5rhno6sltcuhf3****k0603l**

## Step2:

Call API : **/V1/products/** with parameters

```
searchCriteria=*
Put **Header**
Authorization : Bearer at0o6w5rhno6sltcuhf3****k0603l 
Content-Type : application/json
```